# How to block multijob build if downstream jobs will running on same node?

Tags: jenkins

I have a multijob project A that always running on master. This project A has 2 downstream jobs subA1 and subA2 which will run on 2 different slave nodes.

How can I block build of project A if subA1 and subA2 is running on nodes that current build defined them to also run on those ?

Answer (score 0):

> build 1 of project A define to run subA1 to run on node1, subA2 run on node2.
>
> Then, during build 1 of project A is running, I trigger it again (build 2) with same value of nodes to run subA1 and subA2, **build 2 should be blocked**.

You can consider **[Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin)** in order to block the project A build if a job named... project A is running.

[image: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/62063114/build-blocker-plugin.png?version=1&modificationDate=1340569111000&api=v2]

Comment: subA1 and subA2 never run on master, they only run on slave nodes. Project A has a parameter to define which pair node subA1 and subA2 will run on. I want to block build of project A if subA1 and subA2 will run on same pair node that there's a running build of project A already defined that pair node.

Comment: a "running build of project A": that should only occur on master, no? "project A that always running on master"

Comment: Yes, that only occurs only on master.

Comment: So what a "running build of project A already defined that pair node" means, since it does run on master?

Comment: For example, build 1 of project A define to run subA1 to run on node1, subA2 run on node2. Then, during build 1 of project A is running, I trigger it again (build 2) with same value of nodes to run subA1 and subA2, build 2 should be blocked.

Comment: I tried that plugin but it didn't block the build because it still not detect which slave nodes subA1, subA2 will run on. That detecting step is on 'Prepare an environment for the run' -> 'Evaluated Groovy script', which is below step " Block build if certain jobs are running" of Build Blocker Plugin.

Comment: @LongTran This is not about detecting the slave where subAx is running, this is about detecting the main parent multijob  "parentA": if parentA is runnin, don't run another one.